# How to join teams meeting from my own app using intent

Tags: android, microsoft-teams

I have installed Microsoft teams and I have to join meeting from my own android app through meeting request links. Is it possible to achieve ?
I have tried below code, its opening teams app throwing popup "Sorry, we cannot take you to this destination at this time"
Please let me know if anybody has solution

```
  this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
  Uri.parse("msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_M2JlOTk1YTQtOTc2YS00Y2EwLTkxNzYtMmNmYTgxYjA2ZTRm%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2272f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22e7d6f57c-6d9d-4605-8128-14c46a94c498%22%7d")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this code i hope it's work

```
 Uri webUri1 = Uri.parse("msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_M2JlOTk1YTQtOTc2YS00Y2EwLTkxNzYtMmNmYTgxYjA2ZTRm%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2272f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22e7d6f57c-6d9d-4605-8128-14c46a94c498%22%7d");
        Intent webIntent1= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
        startActivity(webIntent1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this below code and I hope it will work.

```
val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_M2JlOTk1YTQtOTc2YS00Y2EwLTkxNzYtMmNmYTgxYjA2ZTRm%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2272f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22e7d6f57c-6d9d-4605-8128-14c46a94c498%22%7d"))



if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {​​
startActivity(sendIntent)
}​​
```